# How to wrap text without regard to space and hyphen

Tags: html, css

I have a contenteditable div where the user can input text. I want the text to wrap automatically, but not like the default at spaces or hyphens, but instead like this:

```
This is some t
ext that conta
ins hyphenated
 words like th
is-thing-here,
 and also spac
es.
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use the CSS property [`line-break: anywhere;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-break)

Answer (score 8):

You could try it with `<pre>` if it is known beforehand. If it is not the usage of JavaScript is good. You could getElementById and format it to your liking.

Answer (score 5):

I think for maximum browser compatibility you should look at the CSS property [`word-break: break-all`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp).

Comment: Both word-break and line-break have great compatibility, but seem slightly different. The [CSS spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text/#word-break-property) for that property suggests that word-break is mainly intended for breaking Latin text within CJK text, but that it will not change the breaking rules e.g. with respect to punctuation. In contrast, `line-break: anywhere` should consider all characters to be truly equal. Neither W3Schools nor MDN are quite clear about this, unfortunately.